How to write the LetsEncrypt ID as file, into the '.well-known/acme-challenge' folder in .net 8.0?
Explaination
I have a main website : https://example.com, built with .Net 8.0 Razor Pages.
I would like to create (If it does not exist) the acme-challenge folder at startup and
when an ID, is sent to the acme-challenge url,
it creates a file with that ID into the acme-challenge folder.
By following many website tutorials, i have managed to finish this till a certain point.
When i pass a random ID to the challenge, I am getting an error as shown below (the file does not exist).
If the file exists, it reads the file, just fine.
I can not understand what is missing for this to work.
Note: I have no previous experience with IIS, or Lets encrypt.
If i am not clearly explaining something is out of ignorance.
Question
How can this be done correctly, for it to work?
The code i have tried:
In the Program.cs:
    app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @".well-known")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/.well-known"),
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true // serve extensionless file
});

// Handle Lets Encrypt Route (before MVC processing!)
app.UseRouter(r =>
{
    r.MapGet(".well-known/acme-challenge/{id}", async (request, response, routeData) =>
    {
        var id = routeData.Values["id"] as string;
        var file = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ".well-known", "acme-challenge", id);
        await response.SendFileAsync(file);
    });
});

app.UseRouting();

On the WEBNET8.proj:
Ps. Not knowing which one will work, I have tried many combinations. as below.
  <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="wwwroot\.well-known\**">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
      <Folder Include="wwwroot\.well-known\acme-challenge\" />
      <Content Include=".well-known\acme-challenge\**">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

The error i get:
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
  Connection id "0HN8GK882NCBE", Request id "0HN8GK882NCBE:00000021": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\source\repos\WEBNET8\WEBNET8\WEBNET8\.well-known\acme-challenge\ftf75rf7t7rfvovr8oiv8o'.
  File name: 'D:\source\repos\WEBNET8\WEBNET8\WEBNET8\.well-known\acme-challenge\ftf75rf7t7rfvovr8oiv8o'
     at System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length()


Actually your code snippets work as designed: you never check whether the file in .well-known/acme-challenge exists, you blindly try to send the file contents, the error logged is the logical consequence.
What you do in app.UseRouter is by the way a VERY BAD idea: a potential attacker could read arbitrary files on your server (at least under wwwroot) by submitting things like ../../else-notaccessible.conf in id parameter.

actually i have created two identical folders, one in the main structure of the app, and another inside the wwwroot . The idea was to use the outside folder, but since i do not know how to do it i was experimenting. Kindly could you explain, which would be the best way to make this work without compromising the system security too?

Your original post doesn't include enough contextual details to provide a solution.

For example: how do you plan to to deploy your app? Hopefully, there will be a complete web server like IIS to serve your site, otherwise I wouldn't reccomend running a standalone ASP.NET app open to public Internet. With IIS you wouldn't need to do anything in your code to implement LetsEncrypt SSL, you just could follow https://www.snel.com/support/how-to-install-lets-encrypt-with-iis-on-windows-server-2019/ (or other tutorial).

I am using a temporary free cloud server which asks me to provide the acme-certificate. But to do this, to generate a lets encrypt cert, i need to give access to the lets encrypt '.well-known\acme-challenge' directory to letsencrypt-win-simple.V1.9.3 app, so it could write a file inside this directory and then generate a certificate. I do not wanto spending money on paying a good server, because the app is not ready yet.
